# ansible's `unarchive` removing files not in the destination directory

Tags: ansible

Ansible (v2.9.6) has an [`unarchive` task](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/unarchive_module.html) which can unzip a tar (etc) on a server to a destination directory. Is it possible to tell it to remove any file in the destination directory which is *not* in the archive file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The documentation explicitly states:

> Existing files/directories in the destination which are not in the archive are not touched. This is the same behavior as a normal archive extraction.

I don't think there's an alternative module that can do that. As a workaround you could delete the destination directory first. Or unarchive to a temp-directory and use the synchronize module with `delete` parameter to copy from the temporary location to the destination directory.

Answer (score 0):

I was after the same thing. For small numbers of files (in the archive) this worked well for me.

```
- name: Unarchive test
  hosts: all
  vars:
    target_directory: /path/to/extract/files/to
  tasks:
- name: List existing files
  find:
    paths: "{{ target_directory }}"
    file_type: any
    recurse: true
  register: existingfiles
- name: extract tar file
  unarchive:
    src: input.tar.gz
    dest: "{{ target_directory }}"
    list_files: yes
  register: newfiles
- name: Delete old files
  file:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    state: absent
  with_items: "{{ existingfiles.files | map(attribute='path') | difference(newfiles.files|replace('./',(target_directory ~ '/'))) }}"
  when: newfiles.files is defined
```